Displaying a notification every x hour in flutter
Im trying to show a text every x hours in android notification. I asked ChatGpt as my only source to write it but it seems it is missing something i can't quite figure out.
this is what i've done so far:
main.dart:
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS)) {
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  }
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
    await NotificationService().scheduleRepeatingNotification();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

notification_service.dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> scheduleRepeatingNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id',
      'channel_name',
      channelDescription: 'description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    const NotificationDetails platformDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidDetails,
    );

    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    final tz.TZDateTime firstNotification =
        now.add(const Duration(hours: 3)); // Start in 3 hours

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      0, // ID of the notification
      'Scheduled Notification',
      'This notification repeats every 3 hours.',
      firstNotification,
      platformDetails,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time, // To repeat at intervals
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle, // Add this
    );
  }
}

pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^6.0.1
  sqflite: ^2.0.3
  path: ^1.8.3
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^18.0.1
  get: ^4.6.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  timezone: ^0.9.0

now what happens when i install it on my phone is that it just dies. app's screen is black and it is stuck. is there anything wrong i'm doing?

have you added POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission ?, becuase posting notifications on Android. In recent Android versions (starting from Android 13, API level 33), you need to explicitly declare the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in your AndroidManifest.xml like below:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

Full documentation is available here
